# First instance of human/centaur romance

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre, romantic-interest, centaurs

Throughout the TV shows *Hercules* and *Xena*, humans being romantically involved with centaurs is pretty common, despite it being so controversial.

**What is the earliest example of this happening in Fantasy?**

It doesn't have to result in a child between them, and it doesn't need to be socially acceptable in-universe. Only that they're together (dating, married, eloping, etc). Not looking for one-night stands.

Comment: In fantasy or in ancient myth?

Comment: Serving as hyper-masculine rapists was one of the major roles of centaurs in Greek myth.  There are probably consensual relations somewhere in Grecian lore.

Comment: @Valorum Fantasy

Comment: I ask because Nessus (a centaur) allegedly raped Deianeira https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_of_Trachis. It's not a great example, but I'm assuming there will be others in antiquity.

Comment: Chariklo (a female Centaur) married Cheiron (a male human/horse hybrid - But note, not a centaur); http://mythagora.com/bios/cheiron.html

Comment: Heracles' last wife was abducted by a centaur.  That's how he died, actually.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Second to last wife, actually.  He remarried again, post mortem.

Comment: One assumes you're not including the original romance that brought about centaurs in the first place!  @Valorum I thought [Chariklo](http://www.hbo.bb/00016chbo.htm) (and https://nikiastro.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/chiron-and-chariklo-a-love-story/) was a nymph.  Though she is now a centaur, if only of the astronomical kind.

Comment: Fantasy or Science Fiction? 1980 James Kahn Novel "Time enough and world" has a married centaur as one of the protagonists (created by genetic tampering, not a mythological creatue), and I think the centaurs in Farmers "The Makers of Universes" (1965) too had relation with women (although given Farmers obsessions "romantic" is perhaps the wrong word).

Comment: My first instinct is to look at the *Xanth* series, which started in 1977 and features romances between all *kinds* of different creatures.  But while centaurs are routinely described as beautiful, even by humans, the only definite "romance" between their species that I can find doesn't show up until 1993's *Harpy Thyme*.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I wouldn't count the centaur created through science, but if there are natural centaurs living in a SF world, that would work

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet If there's something about a centaur and a human, that could work

Answer (score 3):

A minimal example -- the final answer is likely to be earlier than this, but the second of John Varley's *Titan* trilogy, [*Wizard*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/49834.Wizard), has a subplot revolving around a liaison of several months' duration between one of the main characters (a human from Earth) and a "Titanide," a member of a centaur-like species created by Gaia, the central intelligence of the titular biostation in orbit of Saturn.  This novel was published in August of 1980.